# why can't just return model in spring mvc controller for jquery post request

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jetty

Spring mvc + jsp web project, use eclispe jetty plugin to run it, just now encountered a very strange phenomenon.

suddenly in eclipse console I saw below error message

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "...foo%2Fsave.jsp" not found
```

at first let me feel very confused, then I tried these manners to solve it, e.g. clean project, restart eclipse and so on, but still exist this error.

Finally I recall I have modified controller code,at first  the code is

```
@ResponseBody
public Object save(FooDTO fooDTO, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (!beanValidator(model, fooDTO)){
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

but if valid failed , page cannot have any message to display,

```
function(data,status){         
    top.$.jBox.tip(data.message, 'info', {  });
    window.location = "${ctx}/foo/queryById?fooId=${foo.fooId}";
});
```

because data is just `foo` string, so data.message is `undefined`.

when valid failed, will put message into model ,

```
model.addAttribute("message", sb.toString());
```

So I change above controller code to

```
if (!beanValidator(model, fooDTO)){
    return model;
}
```

that is just return model,I think if did so page could display error message , e.g param must >= 1.

but it did not, it have above error.

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "...foo%2Fsave.jsp" not found
```

So why `return model` could cause this error.

Then I tried return another object,

```
return new ResponseDTO(model.asMap().get("message").toString());
```

in this case everything is ok.

So both are return an object, why can't just return `model`?

Answer (score 0):

because if return model, then will get a special `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` -- `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor`, but if return other custom object, then will get a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` called `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`, and in this case `the response has been fully handled and view resolution is not required`. please see source code `void org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception`